How do you count data groups occurring sequentially using C#?
I have been looking everywhere I can but can't find a solution for this so far.
On live data, when building a dataset every minute, once there is three sets of 2s, (for example), I'm looking to set a condition to TRUE forward until there are three sets of 3s then set a different condition to TRUE for 3s. Here is an example of what I mean:

So far, I can count the 2s and 3s in an array or list, but don't know how to count how many groups of 2s occur, then at minute 12, when the 3rd set of 2s starts, set the condition2 TRUE until three sets of 3s occur at minute 29. And set TRUE to the other condition and FALSE to the first condition.

When "current" is "2" and "previous" is not "2" (or first time), add 1 to "new 2's".

Does this data continue indefinitely? So that the next condition in the series would be 3 sets of 4s? And what is the form of this minute data? A list/array of integers?

This data result in the last two columns will switch between condition2 and condition3 only. The twos and threes in the data represent two different variables updating every minute which are bool but could be changed to anything. either one or the other may be true, but both will not be true at the same time. The data is not in a list/array right now but could be if needed for this to work.

Maybe use a dictionary. The keys would be the target values (e.g. 2 and 3) you're looking for. The values would be a pair that contains (MinuteLastSeen, GroupCount) for that key.
Every minute, when you get a value that's the current key you care about, check the dictionary. If there's no entry, add (CurrentMinute, 1). If there is an entry either

update the MinuteLastSeen but not the group count if MinuteLastSeen is the immediate minute prior to the current minute, or
update both MinuteLastSeen and GroupCount

Now, check to see if the condition that at least 3 groups has been reached for the current key. If so, flip the bit to TRUE (e.g. in the 3's array). You can do this without checking to see if it's been flipped before. Also set the bit for the previous target value's array (e.g. the 2's array) to FALSE (if there is a previous target value -- you'll also have to look that up in the dictionary). Again, you can do this without checking.
All this assumes the groups for each key aren't interleaved with each other.

Hi Kit, There maybe be 2,3,2,3 data, it is not consecutive 2s, then 3s.  I am waiting through all that till there are three groups of 2 or of 3 to turn the conditions TRUE.

Not clear what you want to happen. You should update your question with other cases. Like, what happens when the sets exactly line up? You might add why you're doing this.
